# Convert Corpus from quanteda to tm

Tags: r, tm, corpus, quanteda

My data `mycorpus` is in a quanteda-corpus (`corpus`-function from quanteda) which I need to convert to a corpus under the tm package. I know about quanteda's `convert`-function. This, though, only converts a doc-feature-matrix to tm. Is there a quick fix I am missing? tm's `VCorpus(mycorpus)` throws an error message "missing source"

Comment: a workaround could be:
`dfhelp <- convert(mycorpus, to="data.frame")`
`ds <- DataframeSource(dfhelp)`
`mynewtmcorpus<- VCorpus(ds, readerControl = list(language = "en"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a **tm** Corpus/VCorpus directly from a VectorSource wrapped in VCorpus, because a **quanteda** corpus is just a special character vector.

```r
library("tm")
## Loading required package: NLP

# from version 3.0 of quanteda
data(data_corpus_inaugural, package = "quanteda")

VCorpus(VectorSource(data_corpus_inaugural))
## <<VCorpus>>
## Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
## Content:  documents: 59
```

However...  Do you really want/need to do this?

Comment: I missed the `VectorSource` command, thanks: works just fine! I see your point on consistently applying quanteda or tm. It's just that the `content_transformer` command from tm is really straight forward to use, when it comes to writing functions: e.g. `codeao <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) {return (gsub(pattern, "Abgabenordnung", x, ignore.case = FALSE))})` `mytmcorpus<- tm_map(mytmcorpus, codeao, "\\bAO\\b")` is there an equivalent for quanteda? Maybe I'll have to dig a little deeper into `tokens_replace` from quanteda...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dfm you can just use the `as.DocumentTermMatrix` function from the tm package.

If you have a dfm called my_dfm you can use the line of code below. You need to give an option to the weights of the dtm, but coming from quanteda it is just `weightTf`

```
my_dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(my_dfm, weighting = weightTf)
```